# X Bad Access Error in ubuntu (python)

Tags: python-3.x, linux, opencv, ubuntu-14.04

i tried to run the following code in Linux Terminal. The input is from my webcam.

```
import cv2
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
s, img = cam.read()
cv2.imshow(picName, img)
cv2.waitKey(0)`
```

It works fine on my pc however when i tried the exact script in another pc it returns this

> error: X Bad Access error

This is the screenshot of the error.

[image: This is the screenshot of the error.]

I cant seem to find a way to fix it in the internet so please can someone help me. Thanks

Comment: does the other PC has a display? does the other PC has a webcam?

Comment: yes  the camera used is a USB webcam Logitech

Comment: the other pc is accessed remotely using VNC viewer

Comment: the other pc that im trying to access is Liva Z plus

Comment: normally you may have problems doing `imshow` in remotely accessed machines, usally it is solved setting the Display variable... in this case, I have no idea since I have not used the VNC viewer

Comment: okay thanks. I have tried not to access the machine remotely and used monitor for display and there is no error anymore.